# Java try-catch not working

Tags: java, exception

wondering if someone can tell me why my try-catch doesn't work.  I enter a character when I should be entering an integer and the program just exits with the exception.  It's identical to a try-catch I wrote in another program.  Not sure why it doesn't work.  :(

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Lab8FileIO {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int menuChoice = 0;
    String filename, userInput, choice;
    boolean playAgain = true;
    char response;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (playAgain)
    {
        // Display menu and get user selection
        displayMenu();

        do
        {
            try 
            {
                menuChoice = keyboard.nextInt();

                if ((menuChoice < 1) || (menuChoice > 4)) // Make sure user enters a number within the specified range
                    System.out.print("You must enter a number from 1 to 4!");
            } 

            catch (InputMismatchException e) 
            {
                System.out.print("You must enter a number from 1 to 4!");
                keyboard.nextInt();
            }
        } while (menuChoice < 1 && menuChoice > 4);

        // Get input/output filename from user
        System.out.print("\nEnter filename in the format filename.txt: ");
        filename = keyboard.next();

        switch (menuChoice)
        {
        // Write to file
        case 1:
            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filename);

            userInput = getUserInput(); 
            System.out.println("I am writing your input to filename: " + filename + "\n");
            outputFile.println(userInput);
            outputFile.close();
            break;

        // Read from file
        case 2:
            File file = new File(filename); 
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

            System.out.println("I am reading from filename: " + filename + "\n");

            while (inputFile.hasNextLine())
            {
                String line = inputFile.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            inputFile.close();
            break;

        // Append to file   
        case 3:
            FileWriter appendFile = new FileWriter(filename, true);

            userInput = getUserInput(); 
            System.out.println("I am appending your input to filename: " + filename + "\n");
            appendFile.write(userInput);
            appendFile.close();         
            break;

        // Exit 
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            System.exit(0);
            break;              
        }

        // Ask user to play again
        do
        {
            System.out.print("\nWould you like to continue (Y/N)? ");
            choice = keyboard.next();
            response = Character.toUpperCase(choice.charAt(0));
        } while (response != 'Y' && response != 'N'); // Keep asking until user enters correct response

        if (response == 'Y') // Play again
        {
            playAgain = true;
            System.out.println();
        }

        else if (response == 'N') // Quit
        {
            playAgain = false;
            System.out.println("\nThanks for playing!");
        }
    }
```

}

```
public static void displayMenu()
    {
        System.out.println("File IO Options:");
        System.out.println("1) Write");
        System.out.println("2) Read");
        System.out.println("3) Append");
        System.out.println("4) Quit");
        System.out.print("What would you like to do: ");
    }

    public static String getUserInput()
    {
        String str;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Start typing. Hit enter when you're done:");
        str = keyboard.nextLine();

        return str;
    }   
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

File IO Options:
1) Write
2) Read
3) Append
4) Quit
What would you like to do: a
You must enter a number from 1 to 4!Exception in thread "main"
java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
    at Lab8FileIO.main(Lab8FileIO.java:41)

Comment: Post the stack trace, maybe you're trying to catch the wrong Exception *or* you are misplacing the block. You are probably not catching everything, `keyboard.nextInt();` is also called *inside* the catch.

Comment: Note that if the `keyboard.nextInt()` *inside* the `catch` block raises an exception, it won't be caught, because you're already outside the `try` block.

Comment: The other program in which I have a similar try-catch has `keyboard.nextInt();` in it.  I don't understand why that one worked and this one doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

Your program fails because in your `catch` block you have `keyboard.nextInt();`, which throws a new unhandled `InputMismatchException`

```
catch (InputMismatchException e) 
 {
   System.out.print("You must enter a number from 1 to 4!");
   // You can remove this line, since it will be called anyways in the next loop iteration
   //keyboard.nextInt();

   // You can artificially set menuChoice = 1; for example for the loop to continue
 }
```

Comment: Okay, so I removed `keyboard.nextInt();` but the program just continues to run.  It doesn't loop back to the request to enter input again.

Comment: Because in your loop expects `menuChoice` to be between 1-4  `while (menuChoice < 1 && menuChoice > 4)`. You can artificially set `menuChoice=1` for example. It depend on the logic of your program and what you want to do

Comment: @stef2dotoh You should fire up a debugger to help you figure out these kinds of problems. Both NetBeans and Eclipse have great tools to step through your code one line at a time while viewing the values of variables. Alternatively, you can add `System.out.println()` calls to see what your code is doing.

Comment: @Code-Guru, I don't really know how to use the debugger yet.

Comment: @stef2dotoh So it's a good time to learn!

Comment: @Code-Guru I still don't think that will explain why the same try-catch snippet works in another program.  Only the variables are different.

Comment: And besides, I think the point of stackoverflow is to get help from other more skilled programmers.  As I look at the various issues programmers have posted here, I've never seen anyone tell them to figure it out for themselves with a debugger.

Comment: @stef2dotoh You are correct. This is a great place to get help once you have done some work yourself. Part of that is debugging your own code. Some questions posted here won't be solved by debugging. This one will, though. Or at least some debugging will help you understand why your code isn't working. In fact, it would have quickly shown you the answer to your original question about why the try-catch wasn't working.